# Merchant API GetTransactionDetails, FEEAMT parameter went missing?

Tags: api, paypal

So I'm using the merchant API to get some transaction details, makes my bookkeeping easier.

So on November 11th PayPal removed the FEEAMT parameter from the GetTransactionDetails for some reason? I'm using API version 96 which is old but I tried the newer ones but can't get anything close to it.

Anyone know whats up? I'm getting everything except the transaction fee parameter.

This is how my API request looks like

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
$info =  'USER=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com'
.'&PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
.'&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
.'&VERSION=93'
.'&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails'
.'&TRANSACTIONID='.$receipt_transaction_id;
```

Best Regards
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just found out what the problem was...

There was no transaction fee on two transactions from the same person. This is the first time in 20 000 transactions. I have no idea why there would be 0 transaction fee.

When there's no transaction free, there's no FEEAMT parameter.

Comment: I just had the same problem.
For 5 Minutes no FEEAMT was transfered. This made big trouble in my database. I know the user tried to repeat the checkout several times, after around 8 tries finally the FEEAMT parameter was filled out and the transaction worked. I know cause I logged all other tries. 
Not sure what paypal is doing and why this parameter is missing, but you can not really rely on it. Better calculate the fee by yourself.